# SwiftUI NavigationSplitView looses toolbar button when App moves to background - iOS 17 / Xcode 15.0

Tags: ios, swiftui, toolbar

SwiftUI NavigationSplitView on iPadOS 17 looses the toolbar button in the sidebar when app is being moved to background and back to foreground. It does not happen on iOS 17 on an iPhone 15 Plus in landscape mode. It does not happen with NavigationStack.

[image]

```
@main
struct EditModeMoveToBackgroundApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: .constant(.all)) {
                ContentView()
            } detail: {
                Text("Detail View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemStore: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var itemArray = ["Mountain", "River", "Village"].map { ItemStore(name: $0) }
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    @State var selection: Set<ItemStore.ID> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(itemArray) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            EditButton()
        }
    }
}
```

This is a severe bug as it locks the user into edit mode from which one can only escape by cold starting the app again.

Does anybody know of a solution/workaround?

Another less severe bug is present, too: the user needs to tap in the EditButton twice to activate EditMode.

Comment: For some reason I have forgotten to publish the sample code with my initial questions. Now added.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem as well, and I logged a forum post [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/743139)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to remove the EditButton from the toolbar when the app becomes inactive and show it again when the app becomes active again:

```
var body: some Scene {
WindowGroup {
    MainView()
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { scenePhase in

            switch scenePhase {

            case .background:
                print(".background")

            case .inactive:

                state.showToolbarItems = false
                state.editMode = .inactive

            case .active:

                state.showToolbarItems = true

            @unknown default:
                print("unknown scenePhase")
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the view where you define the toolbar item, enclose it in an if statement:

```
.toolbar {
    if state.showToolbarItems {
            
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction) {
            CustomEditButton(editMode: $state.editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the other bug - the need to tap the button twice to active editMode - I worked around the bug by using a custom EditMode button:

```
struct CustomEditButton: View {
@Binding var editMode: EditMode

var cleanUpAction: () -> Void = {}
var prepareEditMode: () -> Void = {}

var body: some View {
    Button {
        withAnimation {
            if editMode == .active {
                editMode = .inactive
                cleanUpAction()
            } else {
                editMode = .active
                prepareEditMode()
            }
        }
    } label: {
        if editMode == .active {
            Text("Done").bold()
        } else {
            Text("Edit")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the state class referencing above I am for using as ObservedObject in the views:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = AppState()
    init() { }
    
    @Published var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @Published var showToolbarItems: Bool = true
}
```